# `A*` removing a node from frontier

Tags: python, algorithm, a-star

This is a `A*` algorithm I wrote, in the evaluation I was told *"Your implementation performs the goal test when a successor is added to the frontier, not when it's removed: this compromises optimality"*. What does it mean "not when it's removed"?

Here's my code:

```
def solve(problem, heuristic) :
    """ 
    A* search algorithm finding the shortest path.

    Returns:
        A list of actions.
    """
    s0 = problem.get_initial_state()
    queue = PriorityQueue()
    queue.push((0,s0,[]),0)  # second 0 is priority
    cost_so_far = dict()
    cost_so_far[s0] = 0

    while not queue.is_empty():
        current_cost, s, actions = queue.pop()
        for successor, action, cost in problem.get_successors(s):
            new_cost = current_cost + cost
            if problem.goal_test(successor):
                return actions + [action]
            else:
                h = heuristic(successor, problem)
                if successor not in cost_so_far or cost_so_far[successor] > new_cost + h:
                    cost_so_far[successor] = new_cost + h
                    queue.push((new_cost, successor, actions + [action]), new_cost + h)
```

**Modified version (Updates)**

```
def solve(problem, heuristic) :
    """ 
    A* search algorithm finding the shortest path.

    Returns:
        A list of actions.
    """
    s0 = problem.get_initial_state()
    queue = PriorityQueue()
    queue.push((s0,[]),0)  # 0 is the priority
    cost_so_far = {s0:0}

    while not queue.is_empty():
        s, actions = queue.pop()

        if problem.goal_test(s):
                return actions

        for successor, action, cost in problem.get_successors(s):
            successor_cost = current_cost + cost
            new_cost = successor_cost + heuristic(successor, problem)

            if successor not in cost_so_far or cost_so_far[successor] > new_cost:
                    cost_so_far[successor] = new_cost
                    queue.push((successor, actions + [action]), new_cost)
```

Comment: This is probably something to talk with your assessor about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your graph looks like this:

```
    9
S ----- G
 \     /
 1\   /1
   \ /
    W
```

You need to get from the start node `S` to the goal node `G` along the cheapest path possible. The S-G edge has a cost of 9, while the edges connecting to waypoint `W` each have cost 2.

Your algorithm would look through the neighbors of `S` to add nodes to the frontier, find `G`, and return the expensive, direct S-G path immediately, without ever finding the path through waypoint `W`.

Instead, you need to perform the goal test for a node when you `pop` the node from the priority queue. At this point, it's guaranteed that you've found the **cheapest** path to the node, not just *some* path to the node.

Comment: I've modified the code, would you mind take a look see if it is valid?

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia right before your quote: "the above pseudocode assumes that the heuristic function is monotonic".

Your code would give the wrong answer on this graph and heuristic (letters are nodes, numbers are costs):

```
Get from X to Z: 

  1   2
X - Y - Z
1 \ W / 3 

h(X) = 2, h(Y) = 2, h(W) = 1, h(Z) = 0
```

The nodes would be expanded in the order `X, W, Z, Y, Z`. However, your program would exit after finding `Z` the first time, and would report the path `X>W>Z`, which has a cost of 4, which is not optimal.